# If and only if all given conditions are true

Tags: python, logical-operators

```
import numpy as np    
def data_verify(source):
        rows = [x.strip().split(' ') for x in open(source)]
        columns = zip(*rows)
        blocks = np.array(rows).reshape((3,3,3,3)).transpose((0,2,1,3)).reshape((9,9))
            #check iff, see further
                return rows, columns, blocks
            else:
                return False
```

Got a sudoku grid in txt as such:

```
3 2 7 4 8 1 6 5 9
1 8 9 3 6 5 7 2 4
6 5 4 2 7 9 8 1 3
7 9 8 1 3 2 5 4 6
5 6 3 9 4 7 2 8 1
2 4 1 6 5 8 3 9 7
8 1 2 7 9 3 4 6 5
4 7 5 8 1 6 9 3 2
9 3 6 5 2 4 1 7 8
```

The function collects all relevant data and will return the respective rows, columns and blocks iff the length of the rows is the same as the columns' (got a few other functions that determine whether the puzzle is legit). I figured it is enough to compare the first row to all the columns (or vice versa, doesn't make a difference). How can I create a check that goes something like:

```
for i in range(len(rows)):
    if len(row[0]) == len(column[i]):
        #do something only if all of the lengths check out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all(len(row[0]) == len(column[i]) for i in range(len(rows))):
    #do something only if all of the lengths check out
```

Comment: Thank you, knew it was something simple, too simple :( I feel so stupid :D

Comment: Note that if it is a `np.array` you are testing for being square, you could just use `len(set(a.shape)) == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the check in a for loop and set a flag if there is any mismatch, this example checks all rows with all columns:

```
match = True
for r in row:
    for c in column:
        if len(c) != len(r):
            match = False

# Only continue if match == True
```